# No Audio Output with X11

Tags: arch-linux, x11, audio

I have a queer issue with my Arch-Linux System.

I am unable to get any Sound Output when playing audio, AFTER starting X Server.

The issue is not with Volume Controls or Sound Card Drivers because, if I start any kind of Audio playback BEFORE starting X Server, I have absolutely no issues. The Audio keeps playing even after X Server starts. But if I pause / stop the audio, on restarting playback, I get no audio output.

Even terminating X Server does not resolve this issue. Rebooting the system though, helps.

I tried with different DE's. Checked with GNOME, XFCE, LXDE, KDE. Same issue everytime. So It's not due to a particular environment, but rather an issue with X.

I am not sure what files I should be checking for this.

Comment: Maybe it's your [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Environment#Desktop_environments_for_the_X_Window_System) rather than the X server itself? How are you starting X?

Comment: No, I tried with various other Desktop Environments also. I am currently using XFCE. But the same issue persists in LXDE and GNOME3. I start X using: `startxfce4 --with-ck-launch`

Comment: The recommended way to start is now without --with-ck-launch. Just plain startxfce4 will do.

Comment: @Salil: Without using `--with-ck-launch` I cannot use the power options on my DE. Even after making the switch to systemd.  In any case, I tried both ways, doesn't resolve my audio issue

Comment: funny thing is I started having the same problem a few days ago on my arch install. Maybe this is some regression or new bug?

Comment: I've been facing this since quite some time now. Did you recently convert to systemd? Because I think, I started facing this ever since I made the move to systemd, but I am not sure.

Comment: This does sound systemd related. Check that you have an active session under logind, otherwise things that previously relied on groups to work will no longer do so. See [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/General_Troubleshooting#Session_permissions) for more info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this problem thanks to help rendered on the #archlinux IRC Channel.

The issue was that for some odd reason, starting X would change the default Audio Output Device to my HDMI Card which was not being used to output audio.

On Arch Linux, I installed the package `pavucontrol` for PulseAudio and used it to reset the default device for audio playback to my on-board sound card.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think its related to Xorg anyhow. 
See if you have proper kernel modules loaded (lsmod). If it works after reboot that probably shouldn't be a problem though.

eg.

```
$ cat /etc/modules-load.d/snd_mixer_oss.conf 
snd_mixer_oss
```

Try running alsamixer or aumix as by default the audio is muted (strangely) or set very low (or not set by your X environment).

Answer (score 0):

Does sound work if you start X with "startx" (not via gdm/kdm etc) and start a minimal windowmanager (like pekwm, not gnome or xfce)?

If it does, the problem is narrowed down somewhat.

Also, check if pulseaudio is started automatically or not.